SSL Certificate - Calling an external REST API from Mulesoft
If a REST API is accessible on the internet and is SSL secured do I need to add the certificate to the mule app?
As an experiment I tried calling https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 from mulesoft and it worked without needing to import any certs etc.
Question is when do I need to add/import an certificate and when I don't?

MuleSoft is a company. From which exact MuleSoft product do you want to call the REST service? Add a [MRE] to the question.

@aled, the product is anypoint studio.

Anypoint Studio is a development environment for Mule applications. You are developing a Mule application that is calling a REST API. Mule executes on a JDK. The JDK distribution has a default certificate store (ie a keystore in Java). If the server you are accessing over HTTPS has a certificate that is signed by a well known Certificate Authority that is included in the default JDK keystore then you don't need to have a custom keystore in your application containing the certificate. If the site exposes a custom certificate it will be probably not be recognized as a trusted certificate and the TLS handshake will fail.
You just need to test it. If you need more details of which certificates are being used you could enable Java SSL debug, but it can be quite verbose and you need to be familiar with TLS concepts to understand it. However the certificates used will be printed there.
